# values not getting edited from input field in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have this input where user enters some string and then we make an api call and shows some suggestions where user can select one of the suggested data .Once user selects any of these , i want the data in input field equal to that which is happening as of now .However user is not able to edit after selecting .I felt that it's some controlled or uncontrolled component issue in react .

```
<SearchRectangle>
          <SearchImageDiv>
          <SearchImg src={SearchImage}/>
          </SearchImageDiv>
          <div>
            <input
                style={{borderRadius:'10px',
                marginLeft:'30px',
                backgroundColor:'rgba(216,216,216,0.41)',
                height:'48px',
                width:'100%',
                  outline: 'none',
                  border: 'none',
                  fontSize: '1.6rem',
                  fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                  fontStyle: 'normal',
                  fontStretch: 'normal',
                  paddingLeft: '10px'
                }}
                value={ this.state.inputValue || this.state.selectedCity || this.state.selectedPincode } onKeyUp={evt => this.updateInputValue(evt)}/>
          </div>
```

We execute this code when user selects any of the suggested value in autosuggest .

```
selectsuggestions =(item)=>{
    if(item.city){
      this.setState({
        selectedCity:item.city,
        inputValue:null,
        selectedPincode:null,
        suggestions:[]
      })
    }
    else{
      this.setState({
        selectedPincode:item.pincode,
        selectedCity:null,
        inputValue:null,
        suggestions:[]
      })
    }
  }
```

We are executing suggestions using this way .

```
 <Suggestions selectsuggestions={(e,r)=>this.selectsuggestions(e,r)} results ={this.state.suggestions }/>
```

Comment: `However user is not able to edit after selecting` do you mean something like `onChange`?

Comment: How you execute `selectsuggestions(item)` funtion?

Answer (score 0):

While using `value` method of `input` tag, the value presented is chained to the value of `value`

So you have two options

1. call `setState` on input `onChange` and then `value` will assign new state to UI
2. use `defaultValue` instead `value`, that way UI presentation isn't chained